# How to update status of source data after commit on ItemWriter in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using ItemReader with paging to get data from the source table. On ItemProcessor one by one I will send a rest request to a service using the id of the item and pass their responses to the ItemWriter to store in another table.

At first read (page 1), each item on the chunk have a status of UNPROCESSED, then after processing and saving their responses to another table, I want to update the the status of all items in the current chunk to PROCESSED.

On ItemReader I'm selecting all items that have UNPROCESSED status.
select * from table where status = unprocessed

My question is how can I update the status of each item in my source table that have been processed after saving the response. Because if I update the status, the paging is not correct anymore because of the update. Page 2 will skip some items.

Comment: If you use a paging reader, multiple queries will be sent to the database (one for each page). Now if you change search criteria in between (the `status` flag in your case), this might impact the result of sub-sequent queries. Using a cursor-based reader might fix your issue. There is a sample that implements the process indicator pattern here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#parallel-sample. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ItemWriter which is writing the response of your remote service can additionally write back to the source table as well. Thus, the item writer should do following

1. write response of your webservice
2. update the particular item id with status = processed